# How to deploy an external location in open shift container?

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, quartz-scheduler, csvreader

I have a spring boot application which is deployed in open shift container. I need to implement a functionality that takes a csv file and deleted the list of users listed in that file inside db which should run every week.
I have implemented this functionality in my local and scheduled it using quartz schedulers.
This functionality works fine in my local as I have placed the csv file in my machine.
The original csv file will actually be placed in a shared location. This shared location needs a separate request to gain the access, since I have raised the access for it I will be able to access it.

My doubt here is, once we deploy the code inside the open shift container how can we enable the reading of the file from that shared location that is configured in application.properties without having any access issues.

I don't know how to achieve this.